# Convert date string to unix timestamp without "date -d" in a shell script

Tags: unix, ksh, unix-timestamp

I've been bashing my head into the wall for some time on this one.

I have a date string in my (ksh) script. It's not the current time, it's some arbitrary time.

How can I convert that date string into a Unix timestamp? I'm working on SunOS 5.10 and AIX, which don't have the date -d option, nor the MacOS date -j -f options.

I only need to do this conversion in one place in my code, so ideally I'd like to do it in one line, but if I have to create a function then so be it

I've messed around with Python and Perl to achieve this in one line. Python came the closest, but I couldn't get it to account for time zone, which I would really like. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi want to clarify if the date is like Fri Aug 22 11:22:16 IST 2014 you want to convert to timestamp like Aug 22 11:22:16 . Is it correct ?

Comment: No, if the date is like "08/22/2014 @ 1:24pm" I want to convert it to Unix epoch time 1408713875.

Comment: To clarify, my date string isn't strictly "08/22/2014 @ 1:24pm", I get the time as an argument and I know it's for today's date, but the point is I can extract out the separate pieces like year, month, day, hour, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I lost whatever I had been trying to do with Python earlier, but looking back at it I've found a solution:

```
python -c 'import datetime, time;print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime("08/22/2014/16", "%m/%d/%Y/%H").timetuple())'
```

This particular command outputs 1408737600, which is 4pm on August 22 2014 on the east coast.